# How to fix "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400()" while using axios API fetch error

Tags: reactjs

```
const getZodicInfo = (sign, day) => {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com/",
    params: { sign: sign, day: day },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "edc6bd0575msh7fb7aa8058de303p15ffd6jsn551bf87a46dd",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  return axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

in this code, the getzodiacInfo function accepts two arguments, sign and day. the function constructs an options object with the required method, URL, parameters and headers for the api request

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't post your API tokens here. If I were you, I'd revoke that token in the backend

Answer (score 0):

change option field params to data, `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request, https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

```js
const getZodicInfo = (sign, day) => {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com/",
    data: { sign: sign, day: day },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "edc6bd0575msh7fb7aa8058de303p15ffd6jsn551bf87a46dd",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "sameer-kumar-aztro-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  return axios
    .request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```